# angularjs ng-quill changing direction affects validation

Tags: angularjs

i'm using angular js ng-quill library. i need the default direction to be set on "rtl", but this will make the $valid option of the related input to true. This problem remains even if i switching between two directions. In "rtl" ---> $valid: true and in "ltr" --> $valid: false

This problem will cause the form to be submitted even if the editor is empty. i need it to be required.
[The rtl version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeUqN.png)
[The ltr version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssSNG.png)
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i myself found the solution.
in cases(like mine) that you don't need the changing of direction you should completely remove the direction option from ngquill config and then in  your css do sth like this

```
.ql-editor {
  p{
  text-align: right;
  }
}
```